# What does なけれども mean here?

Tags: grammar

From a Meiji essay:

> 写生のいひ写実といふは実際有りのままに**写すに相違なけれども**元より多少の取捨選択を要す。

What does なけれども do in this sentence? Is it more like:

> ...写すに相違（がある）けど、元より...

or

> ...写すに相違(がない)けど、元より...

or neither of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 相違無けれども = 相違無いけれども = 相違無いが、